# Proving that commutator algebra of Dirac matrices are isomorphic to that of matrix generators of lorentz group

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, dirac-equation, lie-algebra, clifford-algebra

In the exercise 2.6 for Supergravity by Freedman and van Proyen I am asked to Use (2.4) to show that the commutator algebras of $\sigma_{\mu \nu}$ and $\bar{\sigma}_{\mu \nu}$ are isomorphic to (1.34)

Where

$\sigma_{\mu \nu} = \frac{1}{4}(\sigma_{\mu} \bar{\sigma}_{\nu} - \sigma_{\nu} \bar{\sigma}_{\mu}),\ \ \ \ \ \bar{\sigma}_{\mu \nu} = \frac{1}{4}(\bar{\sigma}_{\mu} \sigma_{\nu} - \bar{\sigma}_{\nu} \sigma_{\mu})$

(2.4) is the identity

$\sigma_{\mu} \bar{\sigma}_{\nu} + \sigma_{\nu} \bar{\sigma}_{\mu} = 2\eta_{\mu\nu}{1\!\!1}$

and 1.34 is the commutator algebra of generators of matrix representation of lorentz group. given by,

$[m_{[\mu\nu]},m_{[\rho\sigma]}] = \eta_{\nu\rho}m_{[\mu\sigma]} - \eta_{\mu\rho}m_{[\nu\sigma]} - \eta_{\nu\sigma}m_{[\mu\rho]} + \eta_{\mu\sigma}m_{[\nu\rho]}$

I have trouble even in understanding what is meant by tow commutator algebras are isomorphic.
Does it mean to show that the commutator of  $\sigma_{\mu \nu}$ and $\sigma_{\rho \sigma}$ is same as 1.34 with m replaces with $\sigma$? Or is it the commutator between $\sigma_{\mu \nu}$ and $\bar\sigma_{\mu \nu}$ that should have this form?

Answer (score 2):

The idea here is based on the concept of a Lie algebra and a representation of a Lie algebra. So the Lorentz group is a Lie group (if you do not know what this is exactly don't worry about it) i.e. a group which is also a manifold.
It turns out that such groups have nice properties, with one being that they (or at least part of the identity component) are generated by what is known as a Lie algebra and the relation that any group element $g$ (cole enough to the identity) can be written as $g = e^X$ for some $X$ in this algebra. This algebra is a vector space with a product (known as the Lie bracket or in your case just the standard commutator).

The idea here is that we can now pick a basis of this tangent space, let's call the elements $T^a$ (think of these as matrices e.g the $m$ you have defined above) and just look at the commutator of these as for any element in the algebra we can write it as a sum of these generators.

We then define our algebra by the relation

$[T^a,T^b] = \sum_c c_{abc} T^c$.

Now a group can generally act on a lot of different objects. For example the lorentz group can act on a scalar field $\phi(x) \mapsto \phi(\Lambda^{-1} x)$ or a standard vector $V^\mu \mapsto \Lambda_\nu^\mu V^\nu$. However, the group is still the same.

This idea is captured in the concept of a representation which is essentially a map from the group into a space of operators on the objects you want your group to act on preserving the group structure. So e.g a map $\Pi : G \rightarrow GL(V) $ such that $\Pi(gh) = \Pi(g)\Pi(h)$. (If you e.g. take the action of the lorentz group on $\mathbb{C}$ this map is just the trivial map, while for vectors it is the identity map).

Now we saw that the group is generated by the algebra via

$g = e^X$.

So what happens if we apply a representation here? We find that this induces a representation on the lie algebra such that

$\Pi(e^X) = e^{\pi(X)}$ for an appropriate map $\pi$. This transforms the condition $\Pi(gh) = \Pi(g)\Pi(h)$ into the condition $[\pi(T^a),\pi(T^b)] = \sum_c c_{abc}\pi( T^c)$.

What your matrices $\sigma $and$ \bar{\sigma}$ actually are, are the generators $\pi_1(m) = \sigma, \pi_2(m) = \bar{\sigma}$ for two different representations of the lorentz group. So the commutation relation should hold for each separately but not for the combination of both!